# Amazon Linux Angular CLI Sass Build Failure: /src/styles.scssKilled

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, sass, amazon-lightsail

node version: 10.16.0 
angular version: 7.3.9

I am trying to deploy an application on an Amazon Linux LightSail instance.  I have deployed everything else I need, but for some reason I am having a ton of issues with npm.

Running ng serve and ng build both get different errors, but both seem to hang on scss files:

```
[root]# ng build
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.3) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
 25% building 12/13 modules 1 active ...14-3!/home/ec2-user/fmf/src/styles.scssKilled
```

The process seems to automatically get killed at the same spot every time.  Note that I did run `npm install node-sass` without errors.

Running ng serve causes a different build issue that I do not get on my local (Windows) machine:

```
[root]# ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.3) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-06-22T21:19:13.472Z
Hash: 4aea67934e7745d72820
Time: 115548ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 285 kB [initial] [render
ed]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.88 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 93.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 738 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/_model/deck.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './DeckSnapshot'.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Source code lives here: https://github.com/lewiskeifer/Finance-Manager-Frontend

So it's possible I have some caching issues as I wasted a lot of time fiddling with updates and version clashes.  If nothing else I will wipe everything and try again, but if anyone knows what my problem is, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like I was running out of memory and the OS started killing processes.  If you are using Lightsail and trying to deploy an Angular app, I would not recommended using the free version (512mb).